# Scifi thriller book. Pilot is in the air and learns that a plague is happening on the ground

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

A few weeks ago I was browsing my local supermarket's book aisle. I saw a book with, I believe, a plane on the cover. I really enjoy horror/sci-fi/thriller books and movies that take place on a plane, so I read the back of this book.

From what I can recall, it was about a flight, already in air, and the pilot learns that there is some kind of plague happening on Earth? That's all that I can really recall. It was a trade paperback, so it may have been released last year, possibly?

It was at my local supermarket, and they don't have a large selection, so it was most likely a relatively popular fiction author. I believe the author was male and his name may have contained initials.

Comment: At least it wasn't snakes.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2034476.Down_to_a_Sunless_Sea - Nukes

Comment: Maybe Dead on Arrival by Matt Richtel? That's got a plane on one version of the cover and it features a plague

Comment: Yes!! Thank you - it was Dead on Arrival!! That's the one! And I will also be checking out Down to a Sunless Sea - it sounds like my kind of read, also! Thank you sooooo much!!

Comment: A statement with a question mark is still a statement.  Either make a statement, or ask a question.  Or do both seperately.

Answer (score 11):

This is "[Dead on Arrival](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32940039-dead-on-arrival)" by Matt Richtel

[Review from sciencethrillers.com](https://www.sciencethrillers.com/2017/book-review-dead-on-arrival-matt-richtel/):-

> An airplane touches down at a desolate airport in a remote Colorado ski town. Shortly after landing, Dr. Lyle Martin, a world-class infectious disease specialist, is brusquely awakened to shocking news: Everyone not on the plane appears to be dead.The world has gone dark.
>
> While they were in the air, a lethal new kind of virus surfaced, threatening mankind’s survival, and now Martin—one of the most sought-after virologists on the planet until his career took a precipitous slide—is at the center of the investigation.

[image: Harpercollins edition cover]

Comment: I've added the Harpercollins edition cover, which matches the question, since the cover at sciencethrillers, Amazon and Goodreads doesn't match.

Comment: @DavidW cheers for that, I always have trouble with images/photos